# how to Magento 2 code debug in remote server with Visual Studio?

Tags: magento2.4.0, xdebug

I would like to increase my development productivity. Is it possible to add breakpoints in Magento 2 server files in Visual Studio? Because there is a plugin called XDEBUG in VS code. I installed it but I do not know how to connect and debug my Magento 2 instance ?
Any guide? or just possible in PHPStorm?

Answer (score 0):

In .vscode, edit your launch.json file as follows:

```
{
    // Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
    // Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
    // For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Listen for XDebug",
            "type": "php",
            "request": "launch",
            "stopOnEntry": false,
            "pathMappings": {
                "/var/www/html":"\\\\IP OF THE REMOTE MACHINE HERE\\www"},
            "port": REMOTE MACHINE PORT NUMBER
        },
        {
            "name": "Launch currently open script",
            "type": "php",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "${file}",
            "cwd": "${fileDirname}",
            "port": REMOTE MACHINE PORT NUMBER
        }
    ]
}
```

In your php installation (in my case it's here nano /etc/php/7.4/apache2/conf.d/20-xdebug.ini)

```
zend_extension = /usr/lib/php/20190902/xdebug.so
# For xdebug 3
xdebug.mode =debug
xdebug.start_with_request = yes
xdebug.client_port = PORT HERE
xdebug.client_host = 'IP OF THE MACHINE YOU HAVE VS CODE INSTALLED AT'
xdebug.log_level = 0
xdebug.remote_enable=1
```

Restart apache and start the debuuger on VS CODE. Place a break point, it should be working ;)